# Delphi - Assign Form OnClose on an existent one

Tags: delphi, events, runtime, assign

I have many Forms on my project that uses the Form OnClose event.
However, I need to add another "generic" OnClose on all forms in runtime.
There is any way to just add the new event method, instead of replace it? So, the form will trigger both OnClose events.

Comment: Consider creating your own TForm subclass and adding your OWN second event that fires.  Instead of having to duplicate code in all your forms, inherit it so it gets used in each of your forms.

Comment: May i ask why you need to assign the generic OnClose at runtime ?! when i attach code at run time, that means that i do not know what the code will preform at design time. As far as i imagine , this is a rare case in cleanup code, as what OnClose is for.

Comment: Actually, I just need to add a dialog of close confirmation in every Form. But many Forms already has it owns OnClose event, so I can't just assign a new method like: Form.OnClose := ConfirmationDialog(); or it will replace the existent method

Comment: @Leonardo - You can attach to OnCloseQuery for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only one handler can be assigned to an event at a time.

What you could do is assign the "generic" handler to each Form's `OnClose` event, and then have each Form override its virtual `DoClose()` event to do their local work.  It can call the inherited `DoClose()` method when ready to call the generic handler.  For example:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure DoClose(var Action: TCloseAction); override;
  end;

procedure TMyForm.DoClose(var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  // do something here...
  inherited; // <-- call OnClose handler
end;
```

The alternative is to implement a multicast delegate for the actual event handler, and then the delegate can call other handlers as needed.  Here are a few blogs on that topic:

[Multicast events using generics](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/multicast-events-using-generics-38865)

[MultiCast Events - Part 1](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/86)
[MultiCast Events - Part 2](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/102)
[MultiCast Events - Conclusion](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/160)

Alternatively, you can ignore the `OnClose` event altogether and implement an Observer Pattern instead (using `DoClose()` to call the observers).  Here are a few blogs on that topic:

[Observer Design Pattern in Delphi](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/delphi)

[Delphi and the Observer Pattern](http://www.nickhodges.com/post/Delphi-and-the-Observer-Pattern.aspx)

[The Observer Pattern](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/the-observer-pattern-690)